# CanCan works wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I can't understand what I've missed.

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      can :read, Post
  end
end
```

---

**post_controller.rb**

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    authorize! :read, @posts
  end

end
```

---

**index.html.haml**

```
- if can? :read, @posts
  you can!
- else
  you cannot!
```

Using this code, I always get `CanCan::AccessDenied in PostController#index` exception. It says there's something wrong at the line #8: `authorize! :read, @posts`

**1.**
If I change code in the `post_controller.rb` like this:

**post_controller.rb**

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @posts = Post.all

  end
end
```

The exception is gone, but I get `you cannot!` from my view. I expect to get `you can!` message.

**2.** If I change `can :read, Post` to `can :read, :all` in the **ability.rb**, I get `you can!` message as expected. But that's not what I want to use.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, either you use `can :read, Post` or you use `can :read, post` while looping `@posts`.

There is no in between.

---

btw, if you use `load_and_authorize_resource`, no need to add `@posts = Post.all`.

They are automatically loaded.

---

PS: why do you check in your controller AND in your view?

Comment: Could you, please, type some code here?
Sorry, I don't get what you trying to say.

Comment: I basically say that the error you face are normal and I explain why